# MySQL Authentication & Privileges with PHP server on different box

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, authorization

I am separating a PHP web server and moving my MySQL db to another box.  Actually two instances on AWS.

I can connect as the user to the new MySQL box but can not execute any queries.

On MySQL:

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'ip address' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON dbname.* TO 'username'@'ip address' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

** changed to GRANT ALL for testing to make sure there were not problems with limiting

Verified User

```
mysql> SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user;
| username | ip address   | *... |

mysql> show grants for 'username'@'ip address'
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for username'@'ip address                                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'ip address' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*...' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `dbname`.* TO 'username'@'ip address'                                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

When I try to open a PHP page pulling info from db I get

```
Invalid authorization specification: 1045 Access denied for user 
   'username'@'ip address' (using password: YES)
```

Everything works just fine on the same box and I know that the user is connecting from the web to db server as that didn't work until I opened the ports on the db box.  I understand that MySQL Authentication runs through a process when verifying credentials but I have not been able to track this down.

Is there some other process I need to do also?

**UPDATE**

This new db box did not have a my.cnf file so I created it, restarted MySQL just fine.  If I add `bind-address = ip address` then MySQL will not start and I get the error of `Starting MySQL... ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (...)`.

Answer (score 0):

After Grant privileges to user you should use **FLUSH PRIVILEGES;**

you will need to FLUSH privileges in order to complete the process.

~K

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned I did so, but that does not fix the problem

Comment: Are you able to connect via terminal from you webserver to your mysqldb box:-  mysql -udbuser -p -hYOUR_DB_IP   replace dbuser & YOU_DB_IP with your details